# Blank Redirect Page with JQuery Mobile (and ASP.NET MVC3)

Tags: facebook, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-mobile

I'm getting a strange issue only Chrome + Firefox. It doesn't repro on IOS or IE9.

Here's the repro:

1. Load Home page `http://example.com`
2. Login (via a rel="external" hyperlink). In my case I use Facebook's Oauth Server Side flow - so this URL is a facebook.com.
3. Facebook accepts the user's credentials and then redirects to `http://example.com/user/callback`. Here various facebook data is processed (it is provided in the query string).
4. The server side code at `http://example.com/user/callback` then redirects the user to `http://example.com`. The mechanism used for the redirect is a `RedirectToAction` from ASP.NET MVC3. This returns a 302.

Expected Result:
User would see a URL in their browser = `http://example.com` and the content all nicely shown. This works on IE and Safari.

Action Result (on Chrome Only)
User gets a URL in their browser = `http://example.com/#base_domain=example.com`
The actual page is blank (no visible content)
However a view source reveals that the content is present.

Action Result (on Firefox Only)
User gets a URL in their browser = `http://example.com/#_=_`
The actual page is blank (no visible content)
However a view source reveals that the content is present.

Additional Info
If I enter the URL `http://example.com/#base_domain=example.com` into IE I get the same 'hidden' content (i.e. blank page with HTML source still present).

I should also note I use the RedirectToAction/302 redirect technique in other parts of the application with no issues whatsoever.

The issue also repros with AJAX navigation turned off.

EDIT: This also works on Safari (OSX + Windows) with no issues. It's only apparently broken on Chrome + Firefox on both Windows and PC.

IOS/Safari: OK
Win/Safari: OK
Win/IE: OK
Windows Phone Emulator: OK

Win/Firefox: borked
Win/Chrome: borked

OSX/Safari: OK
OSX/Firefox: borked
OSX/Chrome: borked

Not sure about Android.

Comment: By IOS do you mean mobile Safari?

Comment: Yes - that's right - Mobile Safari. However I just did a repro on Safari for Windows and works OK (same as IE and IOS).

Answer (score 1):

The best solution appears to be setting the Push State and Hash Listening to false - so chrome/ff completely ignore them. I already had AJAX navigation disabled (there some interesting behaviours with it I hadn't completely accounted for yet with my server side code).

```
    $.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false;
    $.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false;
```

I'll probably wait for 1.1 and stabilise the rest of my code before trying to get AJAX navigation working.